# Hide Header from a selected page

Tags: css, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I'm really struggling with this one - here is the page layout:

Page 1 Header 1 and footer 1
Page 2 Header 2 and footer 1
Page 3 Header 2 and footer 1
Page 4 Header 2 and footer 1
Page 5 Hide Header and hide footer 1

This is a PDF generated visualforce page in Salesforce from some choices so the page numbers are not set and I've managed to complete pages 1 to 4 but cannot hide it from 5 onwards, page code is below:

```
<apex:page Controller="RAMS_Controller" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false"     applyHtmlTag="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page :first {
    padding-top: 0;
    }
@page       {
    padding-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
            @top-center {
            content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
            }
            }
div.header  {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            position: running(header);
            }
div.content {
    }
div.footer  {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        position: running(footer);
            }
div.subfooter {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: SansSerif;
            font-size: 11pt;
            }

div.right   {
            float: right;
            }

.pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
            }

.pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
            }
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="footer">
footer content
<div class="subfooter right">Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
</div>
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div style="text-align:center;font-family: SansSerif;font-size: 11pt;page-break-after: always;">
page 1 header
Page 1 content
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div class="header" style="font-family: SansSerif;font-size: 11pt;">
Next pages header
</div>
<!-- Page 3 -->
<div class="content" style="text-align:center;page-break-after: always;font-family: SansSerif;font-size: 11pt;">
Page 3 content (shows header)         
</div>
<!-- Page 4 -->
<div class="content" style="text-align:center;page-break-after: always;font-family: SansSerif;font-size: 11pt;">
Page 4 content (shows header)         
</div>
<!-- Page 5 -->
<div style="text-align:center;page-break-after: always;font-family: SansSerif;font-size: 11pt;">
Page 5 content - need to hide the header from this page     
</div>
</apex:page>
```

I've tried a number of CSS fixes in the style but can't seem to get the right syntax